# YUMI is replacing ISOs of Windows

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot

I have a few programs that I use at work that I would like to combine into one flash drive. I've had no problems with Hiren's Boot and other programs. The problem is that when I'm trying to put two or three ISOs of Windows, YUMI is replacing prior ISOs of Windows.

So if I have `Windows 7`, `Windows 8` and `Windows 10` ISOs, there's only `Windows 10` that I can boot from. Other ISOs gets replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Windows 8 and 10 are UEFI, and there is no "easy" way to multiboot UEFI ISOs YET

I have tried the exact same before, but found out you can only put 1 UEFI ISO on your drive, but unlimited amount of BIOS (Win7, Hirens, Ubuntu) ISOs on your USb drive

Conclusion: you cannot put more than 1 UEFI ISO on your USB drive.
But you can put unlimited amounts of BIOS ISOs on your USB drive, sorry to break it to you man.

If you still want multiple UEFI ISOS on your drive, maybe this can help [link](http://reboot.pro/topic/18182-uefi-multi-make-multi-boot-usb-drive/)

Comment: I hope this answered your question!

Comment: Well, if the UEFI has no issue handling multiple ESP on the same drive, then...

Comment: Exactly, thats why i left the link, but i havent got it working myself yet

Comment: The only tricky thing probably only applies to those "removable" drive (RMB=1 in their SCSI INQUIRY data), since Windows basically allow only one partition on them. Otherwise you can just create multiple FAT32 partitions in Disk Management and copy the content of each ISO to each of them.

Comment: @Maarten Olijve What about XBOOT? Does it allow more than one Windows? Did you try it? Thank you guys for the answers.